# PHP: replace all occurrences of "[CODE]...[/CODE]" in a string

Tags: php, regex, tags

I've got a string like this:

```
Here is my code sample, its not too great:

[CODE]
<?php
    echo "Some testing...";
?>
[/CODE]

I hope you enjoy.
```

Now I want to replace ALL occurrences of [CODE] ... [/CODE] with the return value of `highlight_string($content_of_CODE)`. The [CODE]..[/CODE]-pair may appear multiple times in the string.

How can I solve this without using eval?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `[CODE]` blocks are not nested, [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is a perfect candidate.

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[CODE\](.*?)\[/CODE\]/', 'highlight_string');
```

Comment: i just saw that highlight_string has a second parameter, how can i set this using your callback method? (i have to set the second param to true)

Comment: Check the docs, it sends `$matches` by default. Not sure about sending a second parameter, but you could always find another way to determine how `highlight_string()` was called, e.g. `is_array()`.

Comment: I'm getting always this error: Unknown modifier 'C'. I'm using this text:
`Ok, ich habe eingesehen, dass Java crappy und buggy ist. PHP For The Win!!`
and your regex...

Comment: Ok, I had to correct it a little bit: `/\[CODE\](.*?)\[/CODE\]/` became `/\[CODE\](.*?)\[\/CODE\]/`. But now I only get the first occurrence, not all ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(?s)\[CODE\].*?\[/CODE\]
```

Answer (score 0):

content_of_CODE = reg_replace('/[!\s+!]|[\s*/*CODE]/' , ' ' , $content_of_CODE);